# Calc/2 predicate

Tags: prolog

I need to define a predicate `calculator/2` that takes a list of English arithmetic expressions and yields a numerical result. The system should be able to handle numbers 1-20.

Example executions:

```
?- calculator([three,times,two],Total).
Total=6
yes

?- calculator([twenty,times,three,plus,five,divided_by,two], Total).
Total = 32.5
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. This is my first time experiencing prolog and I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Is this an assignment for a class and the very first assignment? I would suggest going through a tutorial, such as http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/ or http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online (you can find others by Googling "prolog tutorial").

Answer (score 3):

This is an extremely hard task for somebody who said "This is my first time experiencing prolog and I don't even know where to start."

I'll give you some things to start, but you really need to work through some Prolog tutorials (I've found 'Learn Prolog Now', mentioned by @mbratch in the comments, very good) to be able to do the task.

First, you can define some Prolog facts about number names (since you only have to handle only numbers 1-20, you can simply enumerate all he possibilities):

```
number(one, 1).
number(two, 2).
```

...

```
number(twenty, 20).
```

Then you can define some predicates that work for just two numbers:

```
calculator([A, plus, B], Result) :-
    number(A, ValA), number(B, ValB), Result is ValA + ValB.

calculator([A, times, B], Result) :-
    number(A, ValA), number(B, ValB), Result is ValA * ValB.
```

Judging from your example precedence rules of the operators are not used. Then if the list contains more than 2 numbers (more than 3 entries), you can apply above predicates to the first three list entries, and proceed recursively.

Hope you can continue from here after working through some Prolog tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have been using the ProLog Now site but still cannot figure it out. It makes sense to translate the english phrase into a numerical one first, and to list the obvious operations but as far as lists with more than 2 numbers or operations I am lost. I think that I just don't have enough programming background for it to click.

Comment: @user3335366, following on with Sergey's suggestions, an important aspect of Prolog programming which applies to this problem is the concept of a List and how they are processed recursively. Here is one tutorial (found by Google of "prolog recursive list processing") which describes these concepts: http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc310/Prolog/PrologLessons/LS04-listsSL.htm. Your lack of programming background in other languages may be more of a help than a hurt since Prolog is quite different than just about any other programming language.